# QuartzCore animating shapes?

Tags: ios, animation, shapes

I've look around a little and cannot find a way to do this, basically I want to do shape animation, like the image below. Can this actually be done with iOS 6 API or even iOS 7 API? Everything in CAAnimation seems to be to move the whole layer to another CGPoint but not parts of a shape.

[image]

I could manually do it I guess, put an NSTimer on 1/24 or 1/60, calculate changes to my shape and redraw the incremental shifts until desired shape is reached, but obviously would like to take advantage of Apple's ease-in, ease-out timing effects (and save a lot dev time) too if Apple has API for this. TY.

Comment: Is your shape defined by a CGPath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `CAShapeLayer` which has a property `path` which is animatable. You would have to create your shape as a `CGPath` by using the CGPath functions from Quartz or using UIBezierPath.

Your would have to do something like this:

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 50.f, 50.f);
shapeLayer.position = CGPointMake(50.f, 50.f);
shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.path = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:shapeLayer.bounds] CGPath];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
animation.fromValue = (__bridge id) [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:shapeLayer.bounds] CGPath];
animation.toValue = (__bridge id) [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shapeLayer.bounds] CGPath];
animation.repeatCount = NSIntegerMax;
animation.duration = 2.0;
animation.autoreverses = YES;

[shapeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shapeAnimation"];
```

If the interpolation of Core Animation does not work as expected you should have a look at `CAKeyframeAnimation`.

Comment: Thank you Karl, that worked and my day is going by easier because of it.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone struggling with this stuff like myself, modifying Karl's example, here is a simple experiment with the speech bubble drawing, moving the pointy part on its bottom length with CAMediaTimingFunction thrown in. This is basically what I wanted to do, when someone taps on a defined grid of items, the pointer moves into position to reflect tap selection.

```
    UIBezierPath *spath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [spath moveToPoint:CGPointZero];
    [spath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(320.0f, 0)];
    [spath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(320.0f, BLOCK_HEIGHT)];

    // Pointy part
    [spath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20.0f + POINTER_HALF, BLOCK_HEIGHT)];
    [spath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20.0f, BLOCK_HEIGHT + POINTER_HALF)];
    [spath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20.0f - POINTER_HALF, BLOCK_HEIGHT)];

    [spath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, BLOCK_HEIGHT)];
    [spath closePath];

    UIBezierPath *spath2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [spath2 moveToPoint:CGPointZero];
    [spath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(320.0f, 0)];
    [spath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(320.0f, BLOCK_HEIGHT)];

    // Pointy part
    [spath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(300.0f + POINTER_HALF, BLOCK_HEIGHT)];
    [spath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(300.0f, BLOCK_HEIGHT + POINTER_HALF)];
    [spath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(300.0f - POINTER_HALF, BLOCK_HEIGHT)];

    [spath2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, BLOCK_HEIGHT)];
    [spath2 closePath];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 320.0f, 76.0f);
    shapeLayer.position = CGPointMake(160.0, 200.0);
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.path = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:shapeLayer.bounds] CGPath];

    [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.fromValue = (__bridge id)(spath.CGPath);
    animation.toValue = (__bridge id)(spath2.CGPath);
    animation.repeatCount = NSIntegerMax;
    animation.duration = 2.0;
    animation.autoreverses = YES;

    [shapeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shapeAnimation"];
```